# issues with get path method in java lucene program

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene in Java to find rank documents against a query but I've found error in getpath method code:

```
 String DirectoryName = "Doc50" ;
        File folder = new File(DirectoryName);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)        // loop to read files from doc50 folder...
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())                    // condition if current file is of filetype...
            {

                Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(DirectoryName, listOfFiles[i].getName());
                String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); //read whole document in single string 
                addDoc(DocumentIndexer, contents, listOfFiles[i].getName());     //add document to indexed documents
            }
```

Error I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getPath(String, String[]) in the type FileSystem is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Please help me.

Comment: I would recommend to check your dependencies. I bet you have the wrong ones. Check `FileSystems`: should be `import java.nio.file.FileSystems;` and `Path`: `import java.nio.file.Path;`

Comment: Yes. Eypros is correct.. If you import java.nio.file.FileSystems & import java.nio.file.Path then surely it will work. Can you please confirm that?